# como habilito un input en phyton para que el usuario determine la cantidad de líneas de datos a ingresar

Tags: input

Debo crear un código con varias cadenas de datos en la cual el usuario sea el que habilite la cantidad de líneas (Nregistros = input())  de datos a ingresar y así el programa me deje ingresar esa cantidad de lineas y el if evalue todos los datos de las lineas ingresadas:

```
    Nregistros = int(input())
for i in range(Nregistros):
    humedad,merma,tamiz,rendimiento,precio = (input().split())


humedad=int(humedad)
merma = int(merma)
tamiz = int(tamiz)
rendimiento = int(rendimiento)
precio = int(precio)

if 10 <= humedad <= 18 and merma <= 18 and tamiz >= 15 and rendimiento <= 92:
    print(precio)

else:
    print("NO DISPONIBLE")
```

Estos son los datos:

```
datos de entrada:

5 "Nregistros"
10 15 16 97 45
9 15 17 92 40
11 10 14 92 45
12 15 22 94 40
9 13 19 97 45

4 "Nregistros"
9 11 24 95 40
12 21 14 89 45
12 17 24 91 45
9 14 22 98 45

4 "Nregistros"
10 21 23 85 36
10 15 19 84 51
9 22 24 96 54
10 14 16 97 36

datos de salida:

"NO DISPONIBLE"
45
51
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar noto que tienes un error de lógica, pues al hacer varios `input()` y asignarles la misma variable, solo estas reemplazando la existente y al final el valor que contenga será solo el último ingresado, si bien la respuesta anterior da una solución al problema de agregar datos dinámicamente no toma en cuenta el error que mencioné, además te mostraré una forma simplificada de hacer tu proceso.

Primero vamos a reemplazar el ciclo `for` por un `while i in range(n_lineas):` hacemos esto ya que en caso el usuario ponga un dato no valido (mas de 5 números) volverá a pedirle que lo ingrese, asimismo el usuario podrá detener el ciclo. Con el ciclo `while` vamos a ejecutarlo `n` veces, que será las veces que coloque el usuario, también puede salir digitando la letra `s`, cada vez que el usuario ingrese los datos haremos la comprobación y si es correcta mostraremos el precio, en caso contrario le mostramos el mensaje `NO DISPONIBLE`. Cuando el usuario ponga `s` salimos del ciclo.

```py
n_lineas = int(input("Ingrese el numero de datos que desea agregar: "))

i = 0 #inicializamos la variable i
#repetimos esto n veces
while i in range(n_lineas):
    datos = input().split() #pedimos los datos
    if len(datos) >6: #verificamos que no sean mas de 5
        print("ingrese solo 5 datos") #le decimos que solo ponga 5 datos
        continue #volvemos al inicio del bucle
    elif len(datos) ==1 and datos[0].lower() == "s": break #paramos en caso digite s
    datos = [float(dato) for dato in datos] #transformamos los datos a float

    if 10 > datos[0] < 18 and datos[1] <= 18 and datos[2] >= 15 and datos[3] <= 92:
        print(datos[-1]) #le indicamos que se añadio a la lista
    else:
        print("NO DISPONIBLE") #le decimos que no esta disponible
    i += 1
```

**probamos con el primer bloque de datos**

```
>>> 10 15 16 97 45
NO DISPONIBLE
>>> 9 15 17 92 40
40.0
>>> 11 10 14 92 45
NO DISPONIBLE
>>> 12 15 22 94 40
NO DISPONIBLE
>>> 9 13 19 97 45
NO DISPONIBLE
```

Puedes reemplazar el `while` por un `for`, pero la ventaja de usar el `while` es que aplicamos programación defensiva, lo que quiere decir es que *obligamos* al usuario a ingresar datos correctos.

Comment: gracias Christian, pero necesito es que cuando el usuario diga un numero de lineas, este parámetro sea al que permita la inclusión del numero de líneas al programa para ingresar los datos, por ej si el dice 4 lineas que solo pueda ingresar 4 lines con datos, no 5 ni 3 y así sucesivamente.

Comment: ok ahora edito la respuesta

Comment: @oscarperez lo siento me había olvidado de editarla, pero ya lo hice :)

Comment: hola ya arregle un poco el codigo, pero no veo la manera para que tome todos los datos de las lineas que ingreso, sera que se puede resolver con un array ? que los datos de las lineas los meta todos en un array y de ahi haga corra el segundo for ?

Comment: el código que te di funciona perfectamente, no se que es lo que tratas de hacer

Comment: es que en el ejercio solo debe dar este mensaje de salida : 

"NO DISPONIBLE"
45
51

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126430/discussion-between-christian-and-oscar-perez).

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacer algo como esto ...

```
cantidad_de_lineas = input('Introduce la cantidad de lineas -> ')
for i in range(cantidad_de_lineas + 1): 
# le sumamos 1 ya que la clase range solo genera hasta n - 1
# ahora lo que tengas que hacer con la cantidad de lineas ...
    pass
```